# JQuery Mobile: click events cannot be attached to button after show/hide

Tags: jquery, events, button, mobile

I have a realy strange issue with jquery mobile:

I use a table and hide rows:

```
$('tr ...').hide();
```

Within the table rows, there are defined buttons, such as: button1.

First I call $('#button1').hide and afterwards $('#button1').show to make visible the row, but the button is away, hence I call:

```
$('#button1').button();
```

The big problem is now, that I cannot attach any click events again, and the previous events are away.

I tried the following stradegies to attach the event:

```
$("#button1").click(...); bzw. $("#button1").live('click', ...);

$(document).ready("#button1").click(function() {
  alert(1);
});

$(document).ready("#button1").live('click', function() {
  alert(1);
});
```

Neither the first nor the second variant is working. The last two variants are working but I do not get the correct sender object as event parameter ( i.e.: $(this).attr('id') ).

Do you know a solution for this problem, I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Do not use $(document).ready() in jQuery Mobile! Check [DOCS](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html) for explanation!

Maybe this will help you

```
$('#page_id_blahblah').live('pageshow',function(){
    //do things with button show hide etc..
    //then append event to button after show, or before, or when you want
    var some_variable = 'button1';
    $('#button1').click(function(){
       alert("Button pressed: " + some_variable);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. I found the mistake, it was a bug in my code. By fault, I was not only hiding the table rows but also the buttons. If I just hide the TR's, than the click events are still there. For the bootstrap, I currently use `$(document).live('pagebeforeshow', ...);`, so everything works fine :)